# creating and maintaining local repository ActiveState Perl

Tags: perl, perl5.8

We are still continuing with ActiveState Perl 5.8. We are using lot of modules which were shipped with perl 5.8. Many of these modules has come up with new version with latest perl.

This task has given to me to have a local repository for all supported modules. We will point ppm to use this repository.

I am looking for some starting pointer for this. Two major things which I can anticipate are: a) how to find and download all the dependent module. b) how to maintain these local repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perlmonks has very nice explanation about how to do that.

[Building a local 'ppm' repository (Windows)](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=559293)